# Raspberry Pi 3 connection from MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, ssh, mysql-workbench, raspberry-pi3

My raspberry Pi is currently running as a web-server and is connected to a DNS. I can connect to the raspberry pi via a SSH key through a program called Tera Term and edit information on the raspberry pie. 
I can open MySQL and edit databases. However, i am unable to connect to the SQL database through MySQL workbench and am unable to connect via a module in android studio.

There seems to be multiple ways to connect to the server:

First is;

- Commented the bind address out
- Created a user in a database then    give the user all privileges.

Second is;

- Changed the bind-address to 0.0.0.0,
- Created another user to connect to MySQL with and grant all
  privileges.

Is there a definitive way to connect to the raspberry Pi's database via MySQL workbench? Screenshots would be ideal.

Comment: Have you selected Connection method = Standard TCP over SSH? MySQL server port must be 3306 not 22, and SSH port is defined in SSH hostname. MySQL Hostname probably must be `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Yes i am using Standad TCp over SSH, the error i get is: Failed to connect to MySQL at localhost:3306 through ssh tunnel at pi@192.168.0.16/22 with user admin,
Cannot open SSH tunnel : Error connecting to SSH server: [Errono 11004] getaddrifo failed

Comment: I changed from tera term to putty and converted the ssh file to an open ssh, new error: Failed to connect to MySQL at localhost:3306 through ssh tunnel at pi@192.168.0.16/22 with user admin,
Lost connection to mysql server at 'readingh initial communication packet', system error:0

Comment: I changed MySQL host name to 192.168.0.16 (the ip of raspberry pi) new error Failed to connect to MySQL at 192.168.0.16:3306 through ssh tunnel at pi@192.168.0.16/22 with user admin,
cant connect to MySQL server on 127.0.0.1 (10061)

Comment: Can you connect to MySQL from Pi bash console?

Comment: yes i solved it by changing the host.allow file in the raspberry Pi now the Workbench is rejecting the ssh key, even though the tera term is connecting via the key.

Comment: Solved the tera term key via putty key gen. The type of ssh key used by MySQL workbench is different to the one used by tera term. Use the putty key gen and convert the key to an open ssh key. Works and solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So
Edit the bind address in the conf file to "0.0.0.0",
Create a user and give all privileges via SQL,
Edit the host.allow file to include "All : 127.0.0.1" for local hosts,
Edit the host.allow file to include "All : (External IP)" for connection from (External IP),
Edit the Key used to be an open SSH key, only the private key needs converting. This can be done through the putty keygen.

This is how you connect MYSQL to a Raspberry Pi 3B SQL server.